# Compile code with reference to Android without the SDK

Tags: android

We are building a game for Android that uses a server to allow people to play online. The server shares the same project than the application because it works by serializing classes to exchange messages between the clients and the server. So we have so classes that are both used by the server AND the android application. Of course, the server does not use Android code so that it can be run on a Desktop computer. For now, everything works fine on our PCs.

The problem is that we have almost finished the game and the server and we want to install the latter on a dedicated server. We just realized that it was not possible to compile it on the server (it is a strong requirement that we cannot bypass, we have to provide the source code that will be compiled on the server) because the Android SDK is not installed on the server and Java encounters errors while compiling the shared classes that contains Android code (not used by the server, once again). So we are in a difficult situation as we cannot require to install the Android SDK on the server just to be able to compile the program... Especially because the server never runs Android code so once compiled, the SDK should not be required anymore.

We are aware that it is a design flaw, but we cannot just delete the server and restart a new one with a better architecture right now, we are stuck... Additionally, the shared classes cannot easily be refactored as the whole architecture of the project is based on the fact that the server can serialize them and the client just has to call a method in them that runs Android-specific code.

What is your opinion about the possible solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Install the Android SDK on the server or split the shared code into a library and have two applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android SDK you can find a file called `android.jar`. For example for API level 22 its location is `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-22/android.jar`. This file contains all the public classes and method stubs, so you can use it for compilation as a runtime dependency.

Comment: I've just tried it but it does not seems to work as showed in my reply.

Comment: When using this solution you will not be able to compile any code that uses generated classes like `R` and aidl proxies/stubs.